# Binding form inputs to single object - angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to bind all form element in single object obj like below:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="obj.name">
<select [(ngModel)]="obj.x">
    <option *ngFor="let x in xx" [ngValue]="x">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

I get TypeError: cannot read property "name" of undefined. Please favour where i went wrong.

Comment: It's a bit tough to determine what's going on, without the code for the component itself as well.  It could be the lifecycle, where it's trying to access name before obj is initialized.  If possible, add the Component, and maybe stub out the obj declaration with an empty object in the Component.

Comment: Could you please let me know how obj need to be initialised?

Comment: do you have any specific model for object at app side? Also share the component code to help you

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the object in the component, thus causing error. For normal bindings you could use `obj?.name` but for model bindings that will throw an error. So you can simply declare the object in the component class like so:

```
export class MyComponent {

    public obj: any = {
      name: '',
      x: null
    }
}
```

And the error will be gone.